# CSS issues with Web Forms for Marketers in Sitecore

Tags: web, sitecore

I have successfully loaded WFFM on my local Instance of Sitecore. I have successfully created a Form, I have tested it and everything works perfectly. 
I have also successfully been able to render the form using an .ascx web control and placing it in my "main" placeholder. Very happy so far, with one exception.
when I enter the URL of the page where the form is being rendered, my top Navigaton, Left Navigation, Right Navigation, and footer is all a different font then the rest of 
my site. I have been able to play with the font sizes of the form, but that does not have any impact on the other placeholders.
I don't know what to do to correct this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Also the navbar-collapse didn't close in ipad in all page that has form.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the Webform stylesheet is overriding some of your styles. You can view the webform stylesheet under: \sitecore modules\Shell\Web Forms for Marketers\Themes\

By default the default.css stylesheet is used. To start out you can try to remove any font stylings in that stylesheet, to see if that will give better results.

To fix it you might want to add identifiers to the default.css ensuring that it only points to styles inside your allowed placeholder.